# change ng-repeat data on response from server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a table whose rows are created with ng-repeat depending on how many posts there are.  On click I PUT the posts new status to the server and the server sends back the updated post object. this works fine.

my problem is that, when the ng-repeat includes | orderBy: '-created_at' as show below I can't update the correct post with the new object when it is returned. the index that is being passed to the function is different somehow.  when i remove the filter it works as intended

please note in this code %% %% is ng-bind not {{ }}

*Html*

```
<div ng-controller="BlogCtrl" ng-init="getPosts()">
        <table class="col-xs-12 table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

            <tr>

                <th scope="col" class=""><h4>Created</h4></th>
                <th scope="col" class=""><h4>Title</h4></th>
                <th scope="col" class=""><h4>Status</h4></th>

            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-created_at'">
                <th>%% post.created_at | date:'short'%%</th>
                <th>
                    <span 
                        popover="post.summary" 
                        popover-trigger="mouseenter" 
                        Popover-animation="true" 
                        popover-placement="top">
                        %% post.title %%
                    </span>
                </th>

                <th>%% post.status %%
                    <a href="" ng-click="toggleStatus(post.id, post.status, $index)">
                        <span ng-if="post.status === 'DRAFT'">Approve</span>
                        <span ng-if="post.status !== 'DRAFT'">Set To Draft</span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>View</th>

            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

app.js

```
myApp.controller('BlogCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getUsersPosts = function () {
        $http.get('/blog/userindex/' + $scope.userid).success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.posts = data[0].posts;
    });
    };

    $scope.toJsDate = function(str){
        if(!str)return null;
        var t = str.split(/[- :]/);
        var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
        return d;
      };

    $scope.post = {};

    $scope.addPost = function (userid) {
        var post = $scope.post;
            post.userid = userid;

        $http.post('/blog/create', post).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.posts.push(data.newpost);
        });
    };

    $scope.getPosts = function () {
        $scope.posts = {};

        $http.get('/posts').success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.posts = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.toggleStatus = function (postid, status, idx) {
        var input = {};

        console.log(postid);
        console.log(status);

        console.log(post);

        if (status === 'DRAFT') {
            input.status = 'APPROVED'; 
        }

        if (status === 'APPROVED') {
            input.status = 'DRAFT';
        }

        $http.put('/posts/' + postid, input).success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.posts[idx] = data;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: When you do the toggle/update/put, do you return all the posts or just one?

Comment: The server just returns the post that was updated, now that you mention I guess I could just just change it on the server to return all posts and that stops the extra http request but then its an unnecessary db call.

Comment: I agree. I have something like as it goes but I used it with jQuery dataTable plugin directive. Let me have a think

Comment: On a side note does the orderBy filter effect the order of the posts object?  I can't understand why passing in the index of the post and then setting posts[index] = to the new post won't work

Comment: Just for clarity and debugging you could try it without the filter

Comment: Try this for me coz I can from here. When you get the data back, do `console.log($scope.posts[index])` and see if the ids match, i.e. if that's the row/post you just update?

Comment: Thats how I was debugging it and they didnt match, I just removed the filter and it works great without the filter. I will edit my question to reflect the code changes and then to ask how to get it to work with the filter

Comment: Ok, I don't think you need to get all the data back again. You have a `$http.get` inside your `$http.put` function. Get rid of it and just do `$scope.data[idx] = data`. The `data` it's getting right now is the data from the `$http.ge`t which if I'm right is all the data

Comment: How is it now, any luck?

Comment: yeah sorry that was there from debugging, how it is now minus the filter is working

Comment: Do you absolutely need the filter?

Comment: Let me think about it, thank you for the help so far, I think I do want the filter but I am going to try and make it a button outside the scope of the ng-repeat as I think I did that elsewhere and didn't have the index problem

Comment: No problem. Have you considered to putting your $http requests in a service and then call it in your controller?

Comment: I am not familiar with services or angular (or javascript :p) in general I just started with angular about a week ago, I am loving it though so if you have a link to info on a better way / best practice to organise my http requests with services I would love to give it a read.  I am much more familiar with php.

Comment: Not much but will deco help http://www.phloxblog.in/angular-js-promise-defered-api-implementation-explained/#.UuGJrnk4lcw

Comment: Thanks I have gotten the function to work as intended, seems hacky to me but does the trick I will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare post ids, comparing objects isn't a good idea, IMO. So now you don't need to send `remPost` as a parameter

```
    $http.put('/posts/' + postid, input).success(function (data, status) {

        for (var i = 0, ii = $scope.posts.length; i < ii; i++) {
            if ($scope.posts[i].id === postid) {
                $scope.posts[i] = data;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome that works and it sounds better than comparing objects to me too

Answer (score 0):

The following function works as intended for me, were remPost is the post object from within ng-repeat. if anyone has a more eloquent solution I would love to hear it

```
$scope.toggleStatus = function (postid, status, remPost) {
        var input = {};

        console.log(remPost);

        if (status === 'DRAFT') {
            input.status = 'APPROVED'; 
        }

        if (status === 'APPROVED') {
            input.status = 'DRAFT';
        }

        $http.put('/posts/' + postid, input).success(function (data, status) {

            for (var i = 0, ii = $scope.posts.length; i < ii; i++) {
                if ($scope.posts[i] === remPost) {
                    $scope.posts[i] = data;
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Are you comparing the objects in that IF block? What is `remPost`?

Comment: When toggleStatus is called you pass the post object to it as the 3rd attribute and that is what is called remPost(I am new at all this sorry :p I don't know wtf to name things.  the for loop iterates through all the post objects in the controllers scope.posts object and compares them to remPost and when it finds the one that matches, it sets it equal to the data returned from the server